# Image display based on time

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, image-rotation

I'm trying to create an image rotator that displays certain images at certain times, but also rotates at other times in the day.

When I first created it, I just had it rotate every three seconds. That worked fine. But once I added the code to make a different image show up at different times, it quit working all together. Part of the problem is I'm confused about where I should put the setInterval and clearInterval. Anyway, here;s the code.

```
     <img id="mainImage" src="/arts/rotatorpics/artzone.jpg" />
```

JS:

```
    var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
    var imageArray = ["arts/rotatorpics/artzone.jpg",
         "arts/rotatorpics/bach.jpg",
         "arts/rotatorpics/burns.jpg"];
    var imageIndex = 0;
    var changeImage = function() {
        mainImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
        imageIndex++;
        if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
            imageIndex = 0;
        }

    }

    var newDay = new Date(); //create a new date object
    var dayNight = newDay.getHours(); //gets the time of day in hours

    function displayImages() {
        if (dayNight >= 10 && dayNight <= 12) {
            mainImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[1]);
        } else if (dayNight >= 17 && dayNight <= 19) {
            mainImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[2]);
        } else {
            var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage, 3000);
        }
        myImage.onclick = function() {
            clearInterval(intervalHandle);
        };
    }​
```

Comment: Fix your code so it's readable, please

Answer (score 1):

first of all, all your variables seem to be are global, please dont do that, use an anonymous function-wrapper which executes your code (immediately (read about [IIFE here](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). this is not part of your problem, but just good and clean coding style.

```
(function() {
  // your code here
})();
```

then i think one of your problems is your displayImages-function, which you declare but never call!

just should call it at the end of your code (or just leave it out)

```
displayImages();
```

if you want your images not to be swapped between 10-12 and 17-19 your code should then work as expected. if the images should swap even at this times, you shouldnt put the setInterval into the last else (inside your displayImages-function

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I'll check out that the article on IIFE.