# time based image display

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I am trying to have an image change based on the time of day and out of a list and react to a simple action from the user. i.e. a tap/click.

Example:

- Step 1: a generic "day" image shows in an "image holder" or on a button.
- Step 2: from 17:00 to 18:00 the image changes to a car.
- Step 3a: the user taps on the car image the image turns back to "day".
- Step 4: at 18:00 the day image changes to "night".

  Or:
- Step 3b: the user doesn't tap and by 18:00 a generic "night" image shows at the same location.

I assume it should be something similar to this [Image display based on time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780344/image-display-based-on-time) but in C#

I understand the basics of if statements and creating arrays so i can select a text string out of a list but not how to combine all that to achieve the above mentioned actions with images. I guess this is a common problem with people who just started with programming.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: oh thanks and sorry, i didn't realize i was using a tag.

Comment: What was your intention in placing "C#" at the end of the title?

Comment: make my title/subject a bit more specific.

Comment: Yeah, that's what tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, any time an update occurs, you need to set the image source. You can do this on startup to get the time-of-day, and then do something similar in an event handler for a button click.

```
BitmapImage source;
if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 17)
{
   source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("path_to_day_image"));
}
else
{
   // repeat for other cases
}
MyImage.Source = source;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Deeko this part i understand. However what i can't figure out is where to use this. (same as i can't figure out how to retain the code formation in my comment :S)  It is not the result or the action of an event and the source of the image is defined in the xaml page. :( i.e. i am here: 


``namespace app

{

    public partial class appPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public appPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}``